# Prove that in the group there are the unique identity element and the unique inverse element.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

*DEFINITION OF A GROUP*

A pair $(G,•)$ consisting of a nonempty set $G$ and an operation $•$ is called a group if the following holds:

1. $•$ is associative;
2. $•$ has an identity element $e$;
3. each $g\in G$ had an inverse $h\in G$ such that $g•h=h•g=e$.

*DEFINITION OF AN OPERATION*

An operation on the set G is a function $•:G×G\rightarrow G$.

**Prove** that

1. an identity element is unique,
2. an inverse element is unique.

I am familiar with proofs from textbooks. I want to check my understanding of things on which books are silient.

**PROOF 1**. Let $e_1, e_2$ are two different identity elements.

I know that the operation is the function. Then if I want to calculate the value of $e_1•e_2$ according to the definition of the identity element I must to get to values $e_1$ and $e_2$. But it is impossible according to the definition of the function (operation) (for each element of the domain exactly the one element of codomain).

*QUESTION 1* Does it the correct proof? Especially I am interested in the reasoning part.

**PROOF 2**. Let $h_1, h_2$ are two different inverse elements for $g\in G$.

It would be nice if I could show that this contradicts the definition of the function. But I can do another thing
$$h_1 = h_1 • e = h_1 • (g • h_2) = (h • g) • h_2 = e • h_2 = h_2.$$

It means that there two different but equal elements in the set G. But this is impossible according to the defenition of the set (there are cannot be the repeated element in the set).

*QUESTION 2* Does it the correct proof? Especially I am interested in the reasoning part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof 1:** Yes, the conclusion is that it is impossible.

**Proof 2:** No, the conclusion is not that you have two elements which are different but equal. You assumed that $h_1\ne h_2$ and you deduced that $h_1=h_2$. So, you have reached a contradiction, and you can deduce from this that the assumption that $h_1\ne h_2$ is false.

Comment: Which rule does not allow me to conclude that there are TWO elements $e_1$ and $e_2$ which are equal?

Comment: If there are **two** of them, then they cannot be equal. Otherwise, there would be only **one** of them.

Comment: "...they cannot be equal...". Why? Because of the definition of the set? (No duplicate elements)

Comment: Because of the meaning of the word “two”.

Comment: No. I don't understand. We have the set $A=\{1, 2, 3\}$. But $B=\{1, 2, 2\}$ is not the set because there are two equal elements. It is not possible by the definition of the set. Do you mean this by "If there are two of them, then they cannot be equal. Otherwise, there would be only one of them"?

Comment: When I read you proof, I missed the sentence “Let $e_1,e_2$ are two different identity elements.” I've edited my answer.